# How to fix a scrollbar issue when using flex layout with CSS?

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I am using a front end framework that uses a flex layout. I started creating an admin page where I have `sidebar`, `header`, `main` sections. I want the sidebar and the header + main section to work independently. So if the sidebar has more data than the site of the browser window, it should use a scrollbar - but always try to fill up the whole space, so should have a `height: 100%`. The header + main sections should have a scrollbar, but the header should not be sticky - it should stay at the top even if the main section has lots of content.

I actually managed to accomplish this by adding `overflow: initial` to the `main` section - instead of `overflow: auto`. So the scrollbar is now appearing on the side of the whole container, not just on the side of the `main` section. However, by doing this, the sidebar doesn't get 100% height - if the main section has more content.

How can we fix this by not changing too much on the flex layout? I know for example, by making the sidebar fixed, it will kinda fix the problem, but isn't there a better, more elegant way of doing it?

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
   }
   .container {
    display: -webkit-box;
       display: -ms-flexbox;
       display: flex;
       -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
       -ms-flex-direction: row;
       flex-direction: row;
       -webkit-box-flex: 1;
       -ms-flex: 1;
       flex: 1;
       -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
       flex-basis: auto;
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       min-width: 0;
       -webkit-box-direction: normal;
       height: 100%;
   }

   .aside {
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in-out;
       transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in-out;
       overflow: auto;
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       -ms-flex-negative: 0;
       flex-shrink: 0;
       width: 260px;
       background: #333;
       height: 100%;
       color: #fff;
   }

   .scrollbar {
    top: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       height: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: fixed;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;
   }

   .vertical {
   -webkit-box-direction: normal;
       -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
       -ms-flex-direction: column;
       flex-direction: column;
   }

   .header {
    color: #333;
       line-height: 50px;
       text-align: left;
       background-color: #fff;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
       padding: 0 20px;
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       -ms-flex-negative: 0;
       flex-shrink: 0;
       height: 50px;
       background: #999;
   }

   .main {
       background-color: #e9eef3;
       color: #333;
       font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
       display: block;
       -webkit-box-flex: 1;
       -ms-flex: 1;
       flex: 1;
       -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
       flex-basis: auto;
       overflow: initial;
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       padding: 20px;
   }

   .card {
    border: 1px solid #EBEEF5;
       background-color: #FFF;
       color: #303133;
       -webkit-transition: .3s;
       transition: .3s;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
       box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <aside class="aside">
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
    bar<br>
   </aside>
   <section class="container vertical">
    <header class="header">
     
    </header>

    <main class="main">
     <div class="card">
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
      foo<br>
     </div>
    </main>
   </section>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good hack, in this case, is to put both main+header in one element and sidebar in another, then position these two containers as fixed.

Header should then be absolutely positioned (inside fixed positioned header+main, which would allow main to scroll under header.

Only thing you have to design now is overflow to manage scroll display.